# How to obtain the taylor series of $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ up to the 6th order term?

Tags: taylor-expansion

How to obtain the taylor series of $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ up to the 6th order term?

As far I know, we should use the taylor series of $\cos x$.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts on the problem? Give us some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: Try writing out the Taylor Series for $\cos(x)$. Do you know how to divide polynomials?

Comment: You can try to use the infinite series product formula $$\sum a_n \sum b_n = \sum c_n$$ where $$ c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n  \binom n k a_k b_{n-k}$$

Comment: It is not appropriate to give a detailed answer unless you've given some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960).

Comment: Also note $\frac 1 {\cos x } \cos x=1$

Comment: From $\cos x=1-x^2 u$ with $u={1\over2}-{x^2\over24}+{x^4\over720}+?x^6$ it follows that $${1\over\cos x}={1\over1-x^2u}=1+x^2 u+x^4u^2+x^6 u^3+?x^8\ .$$ Now expand $u^2$ and $u^3$ as far as is necessary to obtain all coefficients up to ${\rm coeff}[x^6]$ correctly. Everything else is collected in $?x^8$.

Comment: @N8tron I think you meant $c_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}$.

Comment: Nice catch saucy you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Let use

- $\cos x = 1-\frac12 x^2 + \frac 1 {4!} x^4 - \frac 1 {6!} x^6+o(x)$

and

- $(1+x)^a=1+ax+\frac12 a(a-1)x^2+\frac16 a(a-1)(a-2)x^3+o(x^3)$

Comment: That is the series for $\cosh(x)$

Comment: @robjohn Opsssss...Thanks!